# Error from selenium IDE: The URI scheme corresponds to an unknown protocol handler

Tags: selenium-ide, uri-scheme

I am quite new to selenium IDE. 
I try to read from an XML file. 
I saw the error on this site but it was not answered (It was stated that the error was with the xml file used, but that seems not to be the case)

The complete error I got is:

> [error] Unexpected Exception: [Exception... "The URI scheme
>   corresponds to an unknown protocol handler" nsresult: "0x804b0012
>   (NS_ERROR_UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL)" location: "JS frame ::
>   chrome://selenium-ide/content/tools.js ->
>   file:///C:/Rommel/user-extensions.js?1447329745072 ::
>   IDEIncludeCommand.prototype.getIncludeDocumentBySynchronRequest ::
>   line 81" data: no]. toString -> function toString() { [native code] },
>   message -> , result -> 2152398866, name -> NS_ERROR_UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL,
>   filename -> chrome://selenium-ide/content/tools.js ->
>   file:///C:/Rommel/user-extensions.js?1447329745072, lineNumber -> 81,
>   columnNumber -> 0, inner -> null, data -> null, stack ->
>   IDEIncludeCommand.prototype.getIncludeDocumentBySynchronRequest@chrome://selenium-ide/content/tools.js
>   -> file:///C:/Rommel/user-extensions.js?1447329745072:81:5 xmlTestData.prototype.load@chrome://selenium-ide/content/tools.js ->
>   file:///C:/Rommel/datadriven.js?1447329745073:53:19
>   Selenium.prototype.doLoadTestData@chrome://selenium-ide/content/tools.js
>   -> file:///C:/Rommel/datadriven.js?1447329745073:102:2 fnBind/retval@chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium-core/scripts/htmlutils.js:60:12
>   ActionHandler.prototype.execute@chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium-core/scripts/selenium-commandhandlers.js:314:28
>   ._executeCurrentCommand@chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium-runner.js:306:19
>   TestLoop.prototype.resume@chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium-core/scripts/selenium-executionloop.js:78:13
>   fnBind/retval@chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium-core/scripts/htmlutils.js:60:12
>   , location -> JS frame :: chrome://selenium-ide/content/tools.js ->
>   file:///C:/Rommel/user-extensions.js?1447329745072 ::
>   IDEIncludeCommand.prototype.getIncludeDocumentBySynchronRequest ::
>   line 81

---

I got it with the selenium IDE command: loadTestData

```
<tr>
<td>loadTestData</td>
<td>C:\Rommel\test_data_file.xml</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
```

The XML file is this:

```
<testdata>
    <test employee="1" type="1" startDate="01.01.2013" endDate="01.02.2013" />
    <test employee="2" type="1" startDate="01.02.2013" endDate="01.03.2013" />
    <test employee="3" type="1" startDate="01.03.2013" endDate="01.04.2013" />
</testdata>
```

I use the next user extension files:
sideflow.js, include.js, datadriven.js, goto_sel_ide.js.
Somewhere I read that the order of the extension files was important but changing the order did not solve the issue.
If I leave the filename blank the error persists, so my conclusion is that the error is not because of the content of the XML file.
I also tried to get the extension files form different sites, but they all seem to be the same.
Help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Solved: after a day of frustration ...
I needed to use the filepath: 
file:///C:/Rommel/test_data_file.xml
instead of 
C:\Rommel\test_data_file.xml

Answer (score 0):

Solved: after a day of frustration ... I needed to use the filepath: file:///C:/Rommel/test_data_file.xml 
instead of
C:\Rommel\test_data_file.xml